# Error waiting to create DomainMapping: resource is in failed state "Ready:False", message: Route XXX does not exist

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform, google-cloud-run, terraform-provider-gcp

I was creating a Cloud Run service and the domain mapping with this Terraform code:

```
resource "google_cloud_run_service" "order" {
    autogenerate_revision_name = false
    location                   = "asia-southeast1"
    name                       = "order"
    project                    = "mycompany"

    template {
        spec {
            containers {
                args    = []
                command = []
                image   = "asia.gcr.io/mycompany/order:1.1.11"

                ports {
                    container_port = 7075
                }

                resources {
                    limits   = {
                        "cpu"    = "1000m"
                        "memory" = "2048Mi"
                    }
                    requests = {}
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

resource "google_cloud_run_domain_mapping" "order" {
  location = var.region
  name     = "order.${var.public_domain}"
  metadata {
    namespace = var.project_id
  }
  spec {
    route_name = "order"
  }
}
```

When I apply that code, the first apply fails.

> Error: Error waiting to create DomainMapping: resource is in failed
> state "Ready:False", message: Route order does not exist.

Then after waiting for couple of minutes I reapplied and it finishes with no errors. I assumed that was because of at the first apply the resource `google_cloud_run_service` was not ready yet.

So my question is how can we configure the resource creation of `google_cloud_run_domain_mapping` waiting for `google_cloud_run_service` to be created first?

Answer (score 3):

If you look at the [example](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/latest/docs/resources/cloud_run_domain_mapping#example-usage---cloud-run-domain-mapping-basic) in the [`google_cloud_run_domain_mapping` resource documentation](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/latest/docs/resources/cloud_run_domain_mapping) you'll see that they reference the output of the `google_cloud_run_service` resource:

```
resource "google_cloud_run_service" "default" {
  name     = "cloudrun-srv"
  location = "us-central1"

  metadata {
    namespace = "my-project-name"
  }

  template {
    spec {
      containers {
        image = "us-docker.pkg.dev/cloudrun/container/hello"
      }
    }
  }
}

resource "google_cloud_run_domain_mapping" "default" {
  location = "us-central1"
  name     = "verified-domain.com"

  metadata {
    namespace = "my-project-name"
  }

  spec {
    route_name = google_cloud_run_service.default.name
  }
}
```

This allows Terraform to realise that there is a dependency order between the two resources and so it will wait until the `google_cloud_run_service` resource has been created first before attempting to create the `google_cloud_run_domain_mapping` resource.

These following links document how Terraform builds a dependency graph between the resources you configure:

- [Resource Behaviour - Resource Dependencies](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/resources/behavior.html#resource-dependencies)
- [The `depends_on` Meta-Argument](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/meta-arguments/depends_on.html)
- [Advanced Documentation - Resource Graph](https://www.terraform.io/docs/internals/graph.html)
- [Hashicorp Learn - Create Resource Dependencies](https://learn.hashicorp.com/tutorials/terraform/dependencies)